# I don't have /run/lvm folder | wiki solution impossible

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I'm following Arch Linux installation guide and after entering this part:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I have an error :

```
Device /dev/xxx not initialized in udev database even after waiting 10000000 microseconds
```

I tried to follow instructions from [the Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Device_/dev/xxx_not_initialized_in_udev_database_even_after_waiting_10000000_microseconds). 
However, I realized that I can't mount `/run/lvm`,
as I do not have "`lvm`" in my `/run` folder. 
Anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to this bit:

```
# mkdir /mnt/hostlvm
# mount --bind /run/lvm /mnt/hostlvm
# arch-chroot /mnt
# ln -s /hostlvm /run/lvm
```

Note that you'll need to do the mount **before** entering the chroot with the `arch-chroot /mnt` command.

If you have already executed the `arch-chroot /mnt` command previously in the current session, you may have to first `exit` the chroot, do the `mkdir` and `mount` commands as described, then use `arch-chroot /mnt` to re-enter the chroot and proceed from there.